# nao consigo recuperar a $_SESSION com ajax e codeigniter

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, session, redirect

estou tendo dificuldades de recuperar uma $_SESSION usando session nativa do php com ajax no codeigniter, pois qdo tento verificar os dados informa undefined. segue o codigo, desde ja obrigado a todos.

controller login

```
if($user->cod_user == 1)
    {


        $_SESSION['admin'] = $user->name;

        echo "<script>location.href='admin';</script>";

    }
    else if($user->cod_user == 2)
    {
        $_SESSION['admin'] = $user->name;

        echo "<script>location.href='vendedor';</script>";
    }
```

na view que recebe (admin ou vendedor) chega como undefined

to suspeitando da forma como estou fazendo o redirect com javascript, pois nesse msm controller consigo vizualizar a session normal.

requisiçao ajax

```
$(function(){

        $('#gestao').slideDown('slow');

        // efetua login no sistema
        $('#bt_login').click(function(){

            $.post('<?php echo site_url()?>/Login', $('#form_login').serialize())
            .done(function(data){
                $('#msg_erro').html(data);


            });

        });
    });
```

Comment: Se os dados estão chegando não tem porque não armazenar, verifique se a sessão foi estartada e debug o objeto user com var_dump()

Comment: esta parte do objeto esta tranquilo felipe pois ja debuguei retornando no ajax. essa parte q ta sinistra na hr q eu faço o redirect com javascript mas nao ta chegando na view :/

Comment: e no __construct do controller ja coloquei $this->load->library('session');

Comment: estranho, certifique-se que também estartou nas views admin/vendedor